# Pointer Arithmetic for a 3D Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know how pointers work for a 1D and 2D array, but I'm trying to figure it out for a 3D array.

For a 1D array:

```
V[i] ==> *(V+i)
```

for a 2D array with C columns

```
M[i][j] ==> *(M+(C*i+j))
```

What would be the pointer arithmetic for a 3D array?

Answer (score 3):

```
M[i][j] ==> *(M+(C*i+j))
```

wrong.  It is

```
M[i][j] ==> *(*(M+i)+j)
```

for 3D

```
M[i][j][k] ==>  *(*(*(M+i)+j)+k)
```

Comment: you're doing triple dereferencing here?

Comment: Isn't this for an array of pointers, not an n-dimensional array?

Comment: @yngum No. 2D arrays aren't arrays of pointers. 3D arrays aren't arrays of arrays of pointers.

Comment: It works because of the way arrays decay to pointers in various contexts in C. But it's not very helpful for understanding how multiple dimensions map to row-major indexing in memory, which seems to be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If the 3D array has C columns and R rows, each slice is C*R elements.

```
M[i][j][k] = *(M + C*R*i + C*j + k)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the subscription using pointer syntax then expanding the pointer arithmetic gives:

```
M[i][j][k] = *(*(*(M + i) + j) + k) = *(&M[0][0][0] + x * y * i + y * j + k)
```

where x, y and z (the latter one unused) are the dimensions of the array.

Answer (score -1):

for a matrix M[X][Y][Z]

> M[i][j][k] = *(M+(Y*Z*i+Z*j+k))